# Untar files larger than 2GB (w/o using libarchive if possible)

Tags: large-files, libarchive

I'm successfully using https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/master/contrib/untar.c as dependency-free code to read TAR files, but that code fails with a .tar file that contains a 10GB single file entry. It actually fails at the check-checksum stage, on the very first 512-byte block, of the first (and only) file entry. And the (octal-encoded, 12-bytes long) length expected at offset 124 seems to be garbage.

I can find very little info on TAR format for large files. Normally 12 octals can encode a 2^36 (64GB) file length, if I'm not mistaken, plenty enough for a 10GB entry, but obviously something more is at play here.

My (corporate) build environment does not allow use of libarchive at the moment, and would like to continue using ad-hoc code for now (see below why). Any info how the the encoding changes for files larger than 2GB in those *header* 512-bytes blocks? Any *flags* to check for extended headers or TAR variant? Any pointers to some doc on TAR specifically for the >2GB case? I didn't find any.

My use case if a little special, I want to decode the custom-binary-formatted files inside the (non-compressed) TAR on-the-fly, in a streaming fashion, recording offsets into those files (and thus the uncompressed archive) for later use. Ideally I'd memory-map the whole archive, streaming decode it, to discover the (inner) files within and streaming decode those, generating *records* (for further processing downstream) which do not copy but reference large chunks of the archive. This is a use-case that I suspect will be difficult to pull off using the libarchive API I'm seeing in the example. But which is easily doable if I have more control over the TAR decoding (like I do now for *small* file entries).

And looking at the libarchive code itself, in hope of finding more info, turned out to be rather difficult... I can't seem to make heads or tails of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, while having gone through the trouble of actually using `libarchive` to solve my issue, I discovered the *man page* for tar actually [explains the format variants](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5&format=html) at a high level rather well... So it's possible I could have sorted this out myself after all. I might later.